# What's the transfer function of this op-amp circuit?

Tags: analog

I have to analyse this circuit to find the transfert function between the input e(t) and the output v(t). I already know how to proceed. First the voltage at each pin and then difference between theses pins should be 0.  I will end up with what I am looking for.

To do so, we are kind of studying each pin separately even though both pins are connected to the same point which is the input e(t). For me at this point the positive input is therefore connected to all the upper part and then the resistor on the minus pin and the output pin should be takes in count while  looking to the voltage of the positive pin.

I tried to do my best to explain my concern.  English is not my native language so please be patient with me.

[image]

Credit: Ecole polytechnique de l'Université De Nantes

Comment: You need to [Edit] your question to add a credit to whoever owns that image. This is site policy.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're asking.  I know you're trying to find the transfer function (and we don't solve homework problems on this site) but it seems like you have a different question in there somewhere?

Comment: HI John, yes i 'am not looking for a response about the Transfer function i know how to find it my question is more about the method to do so because how we were taught to solve such problems, we have to study the voltage first at each input (+ and -). the most systematic way is for (+) to do an impedance divider with e Zc and Zr. But i don't understand why the two resistor above do not interfere given that they are kind of connected to the minus through the imput e(t). if that makes more sense

Comment: In English, the term is op amp; "AOP" would not be recognised by most engineers I know.

Comment: okey thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *I tried to do my best to explain my concern. English is not my native
> language so please be patient with me.*

From a comment under the question: -

> *my question is more about the method*

Break the link on the inputs like this: -

[image]

Then use superimposition theory to find u(t) with source \$\color{red}{\text{(2)}}\$ being grounded then repeat for source \$\color{red}{\text{(1)}}\$ grounded. Add the two instances of u(t).

Do you understand the superposition theorem?